# why when I set button's background image in method called "layoutSubviews", it will not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Like the title said, I want set my tabBar's background image,but I find that when I called the method in initWithFrame like
[image]

It doesn't work and I don't know why.
And I try set background img in method `layoutSubviews` ,it doesn't work too.

Comment: I am sorry that i forget tell that the code is written in  a custom UITabBar.m    and i am so sad for my bad english .... i have tried my best to describe my question.

Comment: Please add the code next time, better than the screenshot.

Comment: why don't you directly use if (self.publishBtn == nil) { self.publishBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)]; ... }

Comment: I'm more concerned with the use of Comic Sans.... But also, why is the `setBackgroundImage` outside of the if statement?

Comment: Thanks for ur advice ! In fact it is the fist time to use Stack Overflow for me so that I don't know how put my code on the page suitably.I am so sorry. :(

Comment: Hhh, I love the Comic Sans so much ,It makes me feel comfortable.

Comment: @BJTUzhengli it makes me feel nauseous...

Comment: @originaluser2 eh..I am sorry ..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to customize a UITabBar, I suggest you to look into the UITabBar's subviews hierarchy, it is not simple as a UIView, So you simply set its backgroundImage won't meet your demand.
Anyway, If you really want to customize your UITabBar, I suggest using the default UITabBar and set its properties or building a component which looks like a UITabBar and has the same function.
What I prefer is using the UITabBar, that is to say use its own property or method as possible as you can instead of adding Subviews, modifying its own layoutSubviews method and so on.